# How to draw Circle using OpenGl in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, geometry

I've been working  on a small app for my phone, and I wanted to add a
feature that needs
a circle to be drawn to screen. I was wondering how I could do this
using OpenGL ES. can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

Basically, there are three options for drawing a circle. You don't specify whether you want a solid/thin/thick etc look, so not all of these might be appriopriate for your case:

1. Generate vertices in a circle and use glDrawArray( GL_LINES, ... ). Depending on how many vertices you generate this will yield a nice and crisp result.
2. Use a pregenerated texture of a circle (with alpha transparency) and map it on a quad. This will result in very smooth graphics and allow for a ´thick´ circle, but it will not be as flexible: even with mipmapping, you'll want your texture to be about the same size you are rendering the quad.
3. Use a fragment shader. Examples like [this](http://people.freedesktop.org/~idr/OpenGL_tutorials/03-fragment-intro.html) should work fine.